# Maximum Principle for Operator $L$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

I'm having some trouble showing the following:

Let $u\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded and assume that $u\in C^{1,2}(U_T)$. Consider the partial differential operator $$Lu:=u_t-\Delta u+b\cdot\nabla u+cu\qquad\text{on $U_T$},$$
with $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $c\in C(\overline{U_T})$. Show that if $Lu\leq0$ and $c\geq0$ on $U_T$ then $$\max_{\overline{U_T}}u\leq\max_{\Gamma_T}u^+,$$ where $u^+=\max\{u,0\}$ is the positive part of $u$.

And where $U_T:=U\times (0,T]$, and $\Gamma_T:=\overline{U_T}- U=(\partial U\times [0,T])\cup(U\times\{0\})$.

I can see this is quite similar to the maximum principles in Chapter 7 in Evans' book, and this can probably be proven in a similar fashion. Altough I'm having some trouble. Here's what I have thusfar:

Assume $Lu>0$ in $U_T$, and assume $u$ takes a negative minimum at $(x_0,t_0)\in U_T$, then $u_t(x_0,t_0)=0$, and $D^2u(x_0,t_0)\leq0$ an in particular $u_{x_ix_i}\leq0$.With this, $Lu$ also become non-positive, thus a contradiction with our assumption.
Then when taking $Lu\geq0$ I don't know how to continue. I tried showing the problem using a similar technique as in Theorem 9 in section 7.1.4. of Evans' book. (also, why does it hold such a negative minimum exists? It's been a while since I've covered this and can't find an argument, although it is used in many other proof as well.)

Any hints are very much welcome!
(I'm self-studying PDE using Evans' book (Chapter 2 and section 3.2) and Lecture Notes provided by my University, which is where this Problem is taken from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you're missing the assumption that $u\in C(\overline{U_T})$, which is essential. Then due to compactness of $\overline{U_T}$ we infer that a maximum (and a minimum) in $\overline{U_T}$ exists. 
Next, if $Lu \leq 0$, you consider $u_\varepsilon(x,t) = u(x,t) - \varepsilon t$ for $\varepsilon > 0$, for which it holds that
$$ Lu_\varepsilon = Lu -\varepsilon - \varepsilon t c < 0,$$
since by assumption $c\geq 0$ and $Lu \leq 0$. If $u$ attains a positive maximum in $U_T$, then so does $u_\varepsilon$ if $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently small, and you get a contraction with the first step.

Comment: Directly arguing by contradiction in stead of the long way around, but splitting it up, does seem like the most efficient way to go. Thank you for your clear answer!

Comment: The notation $u\in C^{1,2}(U_T)$ means that $u$ is 1-times continuously differentiable, would that also work instead of $u\in C(\overline{U_T})$, or am I mixing up some notation and do we need it to be a closed interval?

Comment: @JackpotWizard180 No, in that case you cannot say that a maximum (or minimum) exists. To do so, you additionally need that $u\in C(\overline{U_T})$. (Since continuous functions admit a maximum and a minimum on a compact set.)